# Actionscript-3 file access from SWF embedded into PDF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, pdf

My SWF accesses a text file with the following code.

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\moves.txt"));
```

I have now embedded my SWF inside a PDF and it stops working, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe package the file with the SWF and then access it from there rather than from an external location on disk? Add error listeners, log output and try to debug as to what is going on?

Comment: How did you embed the SWF? You must use a RichMedia annotation and also embed the corresponding files it needs into the PDF (with likely corrected paths to internal PDF stores).

Comment: Another possibility is to just embed (as one) the text file into your SWF during compile time... Look up **AS3 embed external file as class**. This way you shouldn't need `URLRequest` loads etc, just instance the embed into some string var like `myString = new yourEmbedClassName();`. Something like that. Research will find you some basic example / tutorial...